# How to change the status code of a proxied server response in nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I'm having a hard time configuring nginx to act as a proxy of a public S3 endpoint. My use case necessitates altering the status code of the S3 response, while preserving the response payload.

The possible status codes returned by S3 include 200 and 403. For my use case, I need to map those status codes to 503.

I have tried the following which does not work:

```
location ~* ^/.* {
  [...]
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page             200 =503 $upstream_http_location
}
```

Nginx outputs the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] value "200" must be between 300 and 599 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:xx

Here's a more complete snippet:

```
server {
  listen       80;

  location ~* ^/.* {
    proxy_http_version         1.1;
    proxy_method               GET;
    proxy_pass                 http://my-s3-bucket-endpoint;
    proxy_pass_request_body    off;

    proxy_set_header       Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header       Connection "";
    proxy_set_header       Host my-s3-bucket-endpoint;
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';

    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";

    proxy_cache            S3_CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid      200 403 503 1h;
    proxy_cache_bypass     $http_cache_purge;
    add_header             X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page             200 =503 $upstream_http_location;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I need with nginx?

Comment: Read what system tells you. You can't alter "success" return code. It just makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a more or less suitable solution. It's a bit hackish but it works.

The key was to set the index document of my S3 bucket to a non-existing filename. This causes requests to / on the S3 bucket endpoint to result in 403.

Since the nginx proxy maps all incoming requests to / on the S3 bucket endpoint, the result is always 403 which the nginx proxy can intercept. From there, the error_page directive tells it to respond by requesting a specific document (in this case **error.json**) in the S3 bucket endpoint and use 503 as the response status code.

```
location ~* ^/. {
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page             403 =503 /error.json;
}
```

This solution involves two requests being sent to the S3 bucket endpoint (/, /error.json) but at least caching seems to be enabled for both requests using the configuration in the more complete snippet above.

Comment: Just bring backend server down for maintenance, and you will get your error without any tricks.

Comment: But then users will see the load balancer's default generic 503 message. I need to return a custom error message that will eventually be configurable by non-technical people on the team.

Answer (score 0):

Example with gcs storage

```
location ~/ {
    return 503;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
location = /custom_50x.html {
    rewrite (.*) /your-bucket/custom_error.html break;
    proxy_pass https://storage.googleapis.com;
}
```