# nginx redirect on proxy connection instead of proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, web

Got 3 servers

"server3" which runs nginx and two backend servers (server1,server2).

Got the following configuration on server3 :

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location     @onerror {
        return 302  http://server2.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   1s;
        proxy_pass http://server1.com/;
        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 500 501 502 503 504  @onerror
    }
}
```

My goal is , request reaches server3 and it tries server1 , if it can not connect or got other error it redirects to server2.

This works just fine but not fully "optimized" since if server1 works all the traffics goes trough server3, which is not really needed since 302 redirect would do the job and client would be redirected to server1.

Load balancing is not an option if server1 is up and running all clients needs to use it , only if it is down client needs to use server2.

Now for my question,

Any way i can config nginx to "try" to connect to server1 , if it works don't use proxy_pass but use 302 redirect instead ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems i found a solution , not perfect one , but its working.

First i tried :

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location    @server_up {
        return 302  http://server1.com$request_uri;
    }

    location     @onerror {
        return 302  http://server2.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   1s;
        proxy_pass http://server1.com/;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 200 @server_up;
        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 500 501 502 503 504  @onerror
    }
}
```

Which means if we get 200 status code from our server it means it up and we process it on @server_up.

Sadly got the following error from nginx :

```
nginx [emerg] value "200" must be between 300 and 599
```

We can't use 200 code as "error" and it seems there is no way to allow this, so i found a trick/hack on this post :

[How to change the status code of a proxied server response in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560084/how-to-change-the-status-code-of-a-proxied-server-response-in-nginx)

So i changed my config to this :

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location    @server_up {
        return 302  http://server1.com$request_uri;
    }

    location     @onerror {
        return 302  http://server2.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   1s;
        #proxy pass to non existing url so we can intercept the 404 error and we know server is up
        proxy_pass http://server1.com/hgfkdjhgfdkjhgdfkhgkfdjh;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 @server_up;
        error_page 400 401 402 403 405 500 501 502 503 504  @onerror
    }
}
```

We request a non existing URL on our server , if we can not connect @onerror will be triggered but if server is up @server_up will be triggered and we can redirect to server1.com.